# How to calculate maximum NDVI pixel value?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

I tried using `ee.Reducer.minMax() but it is giving different result compared to the 100% stretched range in the visualization parameter.  [image]

And the one in visualization parameter is correct but how to use it in my code other than importing that parameter directly from Map Panel?

Code - https://code.earthengine.google.com/8f38ced2752db3572311d65636c2440e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minMax reducer is the correct answer.
The code editor stretch is doing the same thing, but it is much larger scale, such that the entire area visible on the screen fits in 64,000 pixels.

Comment: Thank you @Noel for replying. But that region is near a deserted area, and 0.78 NDVI is quite impossible. Could you please advise me on how can I extract that Maximum value in the Map Panel layer visualization? And even if it takes the entire visible area into account I don't think Maximum will reduce or is it?

Comment: I don't understand why you think 0.78 is impossible.  Your region includes the Nile delta, which is nothing but farmland, and some portion of those are going to be vegetated, even in the winter months.